# strsplit function in R for data.table

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a table where one of my Columns (mydata$Gene) has some ID's which are in the format:

```
ENSG00000000419.8
ENSG00000000460.12
```

I wish to understand how to use the strsplit function to remove the .xx part

so I want all my outputs to come out as

```
ENSG00000000419
ENSG00000000460
```

etc

so far I have attempted the following code:

```
strsplit(mydata$Gene, ".", fixed=TRUE)
```

but get the error:

> Error in strsplit(mydata$Gene, ".", fixed = TRUE) :    non-character
>   argument

and also

```
strsplit(mydata$Gene, "\.", fixed=TRUE)
```

> Error: '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""."

any suggestions?

thank you for your time.

Comment: Use a character column, not a factor?

Comment: I have also tried strsplit(as.character("mydata$Gene"), "\.", fixed=TRUE) if thats what you mean, and several iterations of it to see where the mistake might be, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `strsplit(as.character("mydata$Gene"), ".", fixed=TRUE)` ?

Comment: I had tried every variation (including that one) that I could think of Marco yes.. and it alway returned Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".\." or something similar. but I think the answer below might be the solution. thanks everyone for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, because your data looks like its a factor:

```
> strsplit(as.character(mydata$Gene), ".", fixed=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "ENSG00000000419" "8"              

[[2]]
[1] "ENSG00000000460" "12"
```

but you might do better by doing a replacement substitute if all you want is the text before the dot:

```
> sub("\\..*$","",mydata$Gene)
[1] "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000460"
>
```